# How do I install stucco over an exterior painted stone wall?

Tags: exterior, stucco

I have a painted stone wall that is not very attractive. I thought stuccoing over it could solve the appearance problem. Would I need a wire mesh? Could I stucco right on the stone? Would I need to remove paint or treat the wall with some type of wash to help the stucco adhere?

Comment: Another solution is EIFS.

Comment: A photo would be probably provide some really good answers, I have stuccoed over stone foundations using chicken wire held in with nails& screws in the mortar but without a photo we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Painted stone will not provide any adhesion for the stucco, and you'll get an uneven surface.  You will need to use some masonry nails and a firing hammer and peg up some expanded steel over the stone.  Aim for where the mortar is, assuming there is some.

Important - Stone walls are not necessarily stable items.  If this is shared with a neighbor, make sure to talk with them about it first. It would not be difficult to crack the stones, and ruin what they think is a beautiful thing.    I'd consider doing a concrete pour - Put some rebar stubs into the wall, add some fencing for extra support, and fill it up.  Great way to add in benches or other features (potting areas, fountains) at the same time.